# Delay in Corelocation

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, cllocationmanager

I've created a helper class for my location needs so i don't violate the DRY principle. The class looks like this: 

 **Location.h**

```
@interface Location : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>{
CLLocationManager *manager;
CLGeocoder *geocoder;
CLPlacemark *placemark;
}

-(float)latitude;
-(float)longitude;
-(NSString *)postalcode;
```

**Location.m**

```
@implementation Location{
    float latitude;
    float longitude;
    NSString *postalcode;
}
-(id)init{
    NSLog(@"Hallo");
    [self setupLocationManager];
    return self;
}

-(float)latitude{

    return latitude;
}

-(float)longitude{

    return longitude;
}

-(NSString *)postalcode{

    return postalcode;
}

-(void)setupLocationManager{
    manager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [manager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    manager.delegate = self;
    manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    manager.distanceFilter = 100;
    [manager startUpdatingLocation];
    geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
 }

 #pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate Methods

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:          (NSError *)error
{

     NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
     NSLog(@"Failed to get location! :(");

}

 - (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{

NSLog(@"Location: %@", newLocation);
CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

if (currentLocation != nil) {

    latitude = currentLocation.coordinate.latitude;
    longitude = currentLocation.coordinate.longitude;


}

[geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocation completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {

        placemark = [placemarks lastObject];
        postalcode = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",placemark.postalCode];
        /*
         self.address.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@\n%@ %@\n%@\n%@",
         placemark.subThoroughfare, placemark.thoroughfare,
         placemark.postalCode, placemark.locality,
         placemark.administrativeArea,
         placemark.country];
         */
    } else {

        NSLog(@"%@", error.debugDescription);

    }

} ];

}


 @end
```

When i in my ViewController tries to create an instance of Location and set latitude and longitude labels, in the viewDidLoad method, the labels are sat to 0.00000.
Apparently it takes around half a second for Location to get the coordinates.
I've tried using

```
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, 1 * NSEC_PER_SEC), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self setCoordinateLabels];
    });
```

But that just seems very hacky and can't possibly be the best practise? So is there any way i could do this a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Well - that is very hacky.  Why don't you forward your delegate methods call?

```
locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:
```

(Btw. this is a legacy function)

Tells you when the first location is set. You can just have an array of delegates on your `Location` class and call every delegate when it's time.

Here is an example with blocks:

```
static NSMapTable *listenerBlocks;

+ (void)addListener:(NSObject *)listener listenerBlock:(void (^)())listenerBlock
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        listenerBlocks =
        [NSMapTable mapTableWithKeyOptions:NSMapTableWeakMemory
                              valueOptions:NSMapTableStrongMemory];
    });
    if (listenerBlock && listener) {
        [listenerBlocks setObject:listenerBlock forKey:listener];
    }
}

+ (void)removeListener:(NSObject *)listener
{
    if (listener) {
        [listenerBlocks removeObjectForKey:listener];
    }
}
```

In your `locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:` you then just call

```
NSArray *allBlocks = [[listenerBlocks objectEnumerator] allObjects];
for(void (^listenerBlock)(NSString *) in allBlocks)
{
    listenerBlock();
}
```

at the end

In the class that needs updates for the labels (e.g. `myLabel`):

```
[Location addListener:self listenerBlock:^{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
      //myLabel.text = //... update your label here
      [self setCoordinateLabels]; // as from your code above..
   });
}];
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! :) 
I've never seen anything about NSMapTable.
So the first the first code example (static NSMapTable *listenerBlocks) goes in the location.m file
And then i didUpdateToLocation (still in location.m right?) get the second part of the code. What kind of method do i call with the ''eventName''? Do i set the labels there? Or what?

Comment: Forget about the eventName - I update the code exampe without it, you dont need it. Copy my edited code! I also added a usage example where you would update your label

Comment: You need the NSMapTable for better memory management than NSDictionary - but basically the same. The listener just won't be retained!